trouble in installation of django
I have been facing many issue regarding installation django on windows using pip. i have used "pip install django".
But I am unable run the command "django-admin startproject myproject"
it is showing following error:
'django-admin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Please help me in installation of django on windows 11. please proide me with commans that to be run for installation in detail.

Use python -m django startproject myproject instead.

Very likely the Path environment variable does not point to the bin directory of the pip that lists the executables (and thus contains django-admin).
The good news is however, we don't need that. Indeed, django-admin is essentially a shortcut of python -m django, so we can work with:
python -m django startproject myproject
instead.
To resolve the problem, try to look for an executable named django-admin, and add that directory to the Path environment variable [Computer-Hope].

recomend using virtualenv
create a venv, activate and install django
PS ❯ mkdir djangoapp

    Directory: C:\temp

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d----        2024-05-14  오전 9:16                djangoapp


C:\temp  on ⛅ (Seoul)
PS ❯ cd djangoapp

C:\temp\djangoapp  on ⛅ (Seoul)
PS ❯ python -m venv .venv

C:\temp\djangoapp  on ⛅ (Seoul) took 7s
PS ❯ .\.venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1

C:\temp\djangoapp via  v3.12.2 (.venv)  on ⛅ (Seoul)
PS ❯ pip install django
Collecting django
  Downloading Django-5.0.6-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.1 kB)
Collecting asgiref<4,>=3.7.0 (from django)
  Downloading asgiref-3.8.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.3 kB)
Collecting sqlparse>=0.3.1 (from django)
  Downloading sqlparse-0.5.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.9 kB)
Collecting tzdata (from django)
  Using cached tzdata-2024.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
Downloading Django-5.0.6-py3-none-any.whl (8.2 MB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 8.2/8.2 MB 10.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading asgiref-3.8.1-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Downloading sqlparse-0.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (43 kB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 44.0/44.0 kB 2.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Using cached tzdata-2024.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (345 kB)
Installing collected packages: tzdata, sqlparse, asgiref, django
Successfully installed asgiref-3.8.1 django-5.0.6 sqlparse-0.5.0 tzdata-2024.1

C:\temp\djangoapp via  v3.12.2 (.venv)  on ⛅ (Seoul) took 11s
PS ❯

run django-admin to start a project
C:\temp\djangoapp via  v3.12.2 (.venv)  on ⛅ (Seoul) took 11s
PS ❯ django-admin startproject myproject

C:\temp\djangoapp via  v3.12.2 (.venv)  on ⛅ (Seoul)
PS ❯ cd .\myproject\

temp\djangoapp\myproject via  v3.12.2 (.venv)  on ⛅ (Seoul)
PS ❯ python .\manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 18 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
May 14, 2024 - 09:18:56
Django version 5.0.6, using settings 'myproject.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.


